# how to tell R to count correctly the numer of subjects in long format file?

Tags: r

I have a csv file that I loaded to R. It is built in long format with
each subject underwent several observations. Therefore, in the column "subject", subject number 1 appeared in 30 cells in this column, for example, and so the other 51 subjects. R is relating to the total number of subjects as 1530 instead of 51!!

How can I tell R to count the number of subjects correctly?

Comment: `length(unique(data$subject))`

Comment: great it worked!! thanks

Comment: but in the analysis will it take into account the 51 subjects automatically?

Comment: Ranin, welcome to SO! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically after `set.seed(1)`), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, i'll try to be more specific in the next questions :)